# passing data from view to api controller having more than one action in it

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

i have more than one method in api controller how to pass data to a specific method from view to that method.

```
public List<ListofUsersusingthisTechnology> getUsersUsinThisTechnology()
{
    return dataHelper.GetListofUsingThisTechnology();
}

public List<TechnologyDocumentation> PostTechnologyDocumentation(TechnologyDocumentation TechDocumentation)
{
    List<TechnologyDocumentation> tech = new List<TechnologyDocumentation>();
    tech.Add(TechDocumentation);
    return tech;
}
```

These two are the actions in my api controller.
I want send data from view using ajax call to a specific action i,e posttechnologydocumentation present in this api controller

I tried calling that api using url but it is giving me an error like
"Multiple actions were found that match the request:"

Comment: What was the request which matched multiple actions?  Are there multiple actions which match it?  (The two in the question are different, so clearly there appear to be more like these two.)  Any given URL should route to exactly one action.  Passing data to that action is done by simply including values in the GET or POST request.

Comment: It seems you have some attributes missing!? Why don't you add [HttpGet] and [HttpPost] to your actions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jquery ajax call for the same. Lets say you have to perform more than one action and pass data to first action only. Then use jquery ajax call and inside success give call to another action.

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : "http://localhost:8080/yourapp/controller/callingmethod",
        dataType : "json",
        data:jsonvar,
        contentType : "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        success: function() { alert('Success!' ); /* call another action here */},
        error: function() { alert('Hushhhhhhhhhhhh error!' ); }
    });
```

Comment: yes iam making ajax call like this $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:31826/api/ViewTechnology/PostTechnologyDocumentation',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                type: "POST",
                data:  JSON.stringify(TechDocumentation) ,
                
                complete: function () {alert("succeeded") },
                success: function (result) {
                    $.each(result, function (index, value) {
                        
                        
                    });
                }
            });

Comment: The `Url.Action` helper should be used to construct URLs so the routing information will be used.

Comment: Then what is the issue? are you not able to send data to particular action call or what?

Comment: yes iam not able to send data to a particular action in api controller

Comment: Did your action call is comsuming the data which you are sending. I mean when you are sending the data as a JSON then your action method call must comsume as JSON.  @RequestMapping(value = "/methodcall", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = { "application:json" })
  public @ResponseBody
  String yourmethod(@RequestBody HashMap<String, String> reqDataMap, HttpServletRequest request) {/*Your code here*/
}

Comment: public List<TechnologyDocumentation> PostTechnologyDocumentation(TechnologyDocumentation TechDocumentation)
{
    List<TechnologyDocumentation> tech = new List<TechnologyDocumentation>();
    tech.Add(TechDocumentation);
    return tech;
} this is my action

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/fwdContact", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = { "content-type=application/json;charset=UTF-8" })
  public @ResponseBody
String method(){/*your code*/}

Comment: You have to write it on both ends one is at while sending request in side the jquery ajax call and the same should also reflect inside your controller so as to know the ajax call that this is method which is accepting what I am passing from controller. But before that your application level configuration is also needed to be configured.

Comment: I got it.I have written jquery like this $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:467123/api/ViewTechnology',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                type: "POST",
                data:  JSON.stringify(TechDocumentation) ,
                complete: function () { },
                success: function (result) {